# Can I use WsFederationAuthentication and social login providers together?

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, owin, adfs

I have an application with two areas: An admin area that uses ADFS authentication and a public area that uses social provider authentication (Google, Facebook, etc).

The ADFS and social login providers each work separately, but when I try to use both at the same time they step all over each other.

Here is my Startup.cs code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
            // I have tried setting this to DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            // SECTION A: These lines work when SECTION B (below) is commented out.
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            UseGoogleAuthentication(app);

            // SECTION B: These lines work when SECTION A (above) is commented out.
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            UseWsFederationAuthentication(app);

            // I have tried switching SECTION A and SECTION B
    }

    private static void UseGoogleAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var googleClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientID"];
        var googleClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientSecret"];

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = googleClientId,
            ClientSecret = googleClientSecret
        });
    }

    private static void UseWsFederationAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var metaDataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];
        var realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = metaDataAddress,
            Wtrealm = realm
        });
    }
}
```

## Observed behavior

---

#### ADFS uncommented

**Go to admin area**

- User logs into ADFS and is redirected back to admin area.
- The `.AspNet.Cookies` cookie is present.
- `Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User` has the ADFS claims.

---

#### Social uncommented

**Go to public area**

- User logs into Google and is redirected back to public area.
- The `.AspNet.ExternalCookie` is present.
- I construct a ClaimsIdentity and store it in a FedAuth cookie.

---

#### Both uncommented

**Admin area first, public area second**

- Go to admin area

  - User logs into ADFS and is redirected back to admin area.
  - The `.AspNet.Cookies` cookie is ***NOT*** present.
  - The `.AspNet.ExternalCookies` cookie ***IS*** present.
  - ADFS is sending back the correct claims but they are no longer present in `Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User`
- Go to the public area

  - The `.AspNet.ExternalCookies` cookie is present with the ***SAME*** value.
  - Login in with Google.
  - The `.AspNet.ExternalCookies` cookie is present but with a ***DIFFERENT*** value.

**Public area first, admin area second**

- Go to the public area

  - User logs into Google and is redirected back to public area.
  - The `.AspNet.ExternalCookies` cookie is present.
- Go to the admin area

  - Login with ADFS.
  - The claims are sent back from ADFS but are no longer present in `Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final working code:

Ultimately, there needs to be two different cookies - one for ADFS and one for external providers. `UseWsFederationAuthentication` and `UseExternalSignInCookie` each presume things that cause problems for the other.

Specifically, `app.UseExternalSignInCookie` sets the default authentication type (see source below).

```
public static void UseExternalSignInCookie(this IAppBuilder app, string externalAuthenticationType)
{
    if (app == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(externalAuthenticationType);
    IAppBuilder app1 = app;
    CookieAuthenticationOptions authenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();
    authenticationOptions.AuthenticationType = externalAuthenticationType;
    authenticationOptions.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
    authenticationOptions.CookieName = ".AspNet." + externalAuthenticationType;
    authenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);
    CookieAuthenticationOptions options = authenticationOptions;
    app1.UseCookieAuthentication(options);
}
```

Notice it calls `app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(externalAuthenticationType)`

If you don't set `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.TokenValidationParameters.AuthenticationType`, `UseWsFederationAuthentication` will use the default authentication type (i.e. the one set by `app.UseExternalSignInCookie`).

I'm guessing OWIN uses AuthenticationType as a key when creating, serializing, and deserializing authentication cookies. Since ADFS and external providers are   using the same AuthenticationType (i.e. ExternalCookie), OWIN can't determine which one to use and overwrites the WsFederation cookie.

There are other minor details but this is the main one.